# Pandas: Combine rows with consecutive dates (with NaT) within groups of same id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to combine rows of same id with consecutive dates and same features values.

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Id      Start       End         Feature1  Feature2
0   A       2020-01-01  2020-01-15  1         1
1   A       2020-01-16  2020-01-30  1         1
2   A       2020-01-31  2020-02-15  0         1
3   A       2020-07-01  2020-07-15  0         1
4   B       2020-01-31  2020-02-15  0         0
5   B       2020-02-16  NaT         0         0
```

An the expected result is:

```
    Id      Start       End         Feature1  Feature2
0   A       2020-01-01  2020-01-30  1         1
1   A       2020-01-31  2020-02-15  0         1
2   A       2020-07-01  2020-07-15  0         1
3   B       2020-01-31  NaT         0         0
```

I have been trying other posts answers but they don't really match with my use case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach by:

1. Get the day diff of each consecutive entries within same group by substracting current `Start` with last `End` with the group using [`GroupBy.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html).
2. Set group number `group_no` such that new group number is issued when day diff with previous entry within the group is greater than 1.
3. Then, group by `Id` and `group_no` and aggregate for each group the `Start` and `End` dates using [`.gropuby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)

As there is `NaT` data within the grouping, we need to specify `dropna=False` during grouping. Furthermore, to get the last entry of `End` within the group, we use `x.iloc[-1]` instead of `last`.

```
# convert to datetime format if not already in datetime
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])

# sort by columns `Id` and `Start` if not already in this sequence 
df = df.sort_values(['Id', 'Start'])

day_diff = (df['Start'] - df['End'].groupby([df['Id'], df['Feature1'], df['Feature2']]).shift()).dt.days

group_no = (day_diff.isna() | day_diff.gt(1)).cumsum()

df_out = (df.groupby(['Id', group_no], dropna=False, as_index=False)
            .agg({'Id': 'first',
                  'Start': 'first',
                  'End': lambda x: x.iloc[-1],
                  'Feature1': 'first',
                  'Feature2': 'first',
                }))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  Id      Start        End  Feature1  Feature2
0  A 2020-01-01 2020-01-30         1         1
1  A 2020-01-31 2020-02-15         0         1
2  A 2020-07-01 2020-07-15         0         1
3  B 2020-01-31        NaT         0         0
```

Comment: Great use of cumsum. Learned a lot from that answer, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Extract months from both date column

```py
df['sMonth'] = df['Start'].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.month
df['eMonth'] = df['End'].apply(pd.to_datetime).dt.month
```

Now groupby data frame with `['Id','Feature1','Feature2','sMonth','eMonth']` and we get result

```py
df.groupby(['Id','Feature1','Feature2','sMonth','eMonth']).agg({'Start':'min','End':'max'}).reset_index().drop(['sMonth','eMonth'],axis=1)
```

Result

```py
  Id  Feature1  Feature2       Start         End
0  A         0         1  2020-01-31  2020-02-15
1  A         0         1  2020-07-01  2020-07-15
2  A         1         1  2020-01-01  2020-01-30
3  B         0         0  2020-01-31  2020-02-15
```