# Merge overlapping / adjacent time intervals and drop inclusive intervals with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find a way in pandas to

1. Merge adjacent (+1 day) or partly overlapping time intervals
2. Remove rows with an interval that is inclusive

Here is an example of the Dataset that I'm using:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        [42,1,'1990-01-01','2099-12-31'],
        [42,2,'1990-01-01','2099-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2010-10-01','2016-02-29'],
        [42,2,'2011-09-01','2014-09-30'],
        [42,2,'2012-04-01','2016-07-31'],
        [42,2,'2013-04-01','2014-06-30'],
        [42,2,'2013-09-01','2014-02-28'],
        [42,2,'2014-03-01','2017-04-30'],
        [42,2,'2014-10-01','2017-10-31'],
        [42,2,'2015-04-01','2015-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2016-03-01','2020-03-31'],
        [42,2,'2016-08-01','2016-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2017-01-01','2018-08-31'],
        [42,2,'2017-05-01','2018-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2017-11-01','2021-06-14'],
        [42,2,'2018-09-01','2019-01-31'],
        [42,2,'2019-02-01','2019-05-31'],
        [42,2,'2019-04-01','2021-03-31'],
        [42,2,'2019-06-01','2020-07-31'],
        [42,2,'2020-08-01','2021-03-14'],
        [42,2,'2021-03-15','2021-06-30'],
        [43,1,'1998-01-01','2001-12-31'],
        [43,1,'2010-03-15','2021-06-30'],
        [43,1,'2021-01-01','2021-12-31'],
        [43,2,'1998-01-01','1998-12-31'],
        [43,2,'1999-01-01','2000-12-31'],
        [43,2,'2001-01-01','2021-06-30']
    ], columns=['Id', 'SubId', 'Start', 'End'])
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])
```

### Expected Output

The data I expect:

```
42, 1, 1990-01-01, 2099-12-31
42, 2, 1990-01-01, 2099-12-31
43, 1, 1998-01-01, 2001-12-31
43, 1, 2010-03-15, 2021-12-31
43, 2, 1998-01-01, 2021-06-30
```

### Tested (not correctly working) Solution

Based on the solution to a similar problem [Pandas: Combine rows with consecutive dates (with NaT) within groups of same id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69492855/pandas-combine-rows-with-consecutive-dates-with-nat-within-groups-of-same-id) I have implemented their solution, but it does not yield the expected result

```py
df = df.sort_values(['Id', 'SubId', 'Start'])
day_diff = (df['Start'] - df['End'].groupby([df['Id'], df['SubId']]).shift()).dt.days
group_no = (day_diff.isna() | day_diff.gt(1)).cumsum()
df_out = (df.groupby(['Id', 'SubId', group_no], dropna=False, as_index=False)
            .agg({'Id': 'first',
                  'SubId': 'first',
                  'Start': 'first',
                  'End': lambda x: x.iloc[-1]
                }))
```

As far as I understand the solution will work fine if all intervals are adjacent to each other, but if there is an overarching interval it will not *remember* the overarching interval.

```
42 ,1 , 1990-01-01, 2099-12-31
42 ,2 , 1990-01-01, 2015-12-31  <-- Wrong End date; expected 2099-12-31
42 ,2 , 2016-03-01, 2021-06-30  <-- Wrong; Should no be there, but included in above
43 ,1 , 1998-01-01, 2001-12-31
43 ,1 , 2010-03-15, 2021-12-31
43 ,2 , 1998-01-01, 2021-06-30
```

What would be interesting to know is: If it would be possible to keep track of the min Start and max End while iterating over the same Id, SubId pair.

Comment: Do you mind to add the expected output? I guess that here you have problems with id=42 and subid=2 isn't?

Comment: @rpanai I already put it in the question

Comment: There are two lines with a comment Wrong, Wrong End. I assume that's not the expected output.

Comment: Under the sample dataframe I wrote "The data I expect" followed by the expected data set. I added Heading to emphasize it more

Comment: So, IIUC, regarding point 2 you just want to delete all intervals that included on another one?

Comment: I will suggest you to remove this element `[42,2,'1990-01-01','2099-12-31']` from your data. This allows you to have a more general problem. I can see a solution using two loops but I need to think if there is something better.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution which is working (tm). If anyone has a better solution, please share it!

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
        [42,1,'1990-01-01','2099-12-31'],
        [42,2,'1990-01-01','2099-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2010-10-01','2016-02-29'],
        [42,2,'2011-09-01','2014-09-30'],
        [42,2,'2012-04-01','2016-07-31'],
        [42,2,'2013-04-01','2014-06-30'],
        [42,2,'2013-09-01','2014-02-28'],
        [42,2,'2014-03-01','2017-04-30'],
        [42,2,'2014-10-01','2017-10-31'],
        [42,2,'2015-04-01','2015-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2016-03-01','2020-03-31'],
        [42,2,'2016-08-01','2016-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2017-01-01','2018-08-31'],
        [42,2,'2017-05-01','2018-12-31'],
        [42,2,'2017-11-01','2021-06-14'],
        [42,2,'2018-09-01','2019-01-31'],
        [42,2,'2019-02-01','2019-05-31'],
        [42,2,'2019-04-01','2021-03-31'],
        [42,2,'2019-06-01','2020-07-31'],
        [42,2,'2020-08-01','2021-03-14'],
        [42,2,'2021-03-15','2021-06-30'],
        [43,1,'1998-01-01','2001-12-31'],
        [43,1,'2010-03-15','2021-06-30'],
        [43,1,'2021-01-01','2021-12-31'],
        [43,2,'1998-01-01','1998-12-31'],
        [43,2,'1999-01-01','2000-12-31'],
        [43,2,'2001-01-01','2021-06-30']
    ], columns=['Id', 'SubId', 'Start', 'End'])
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])
df.set_index(['Id', 'SubId'], inplace=True)
df = df.sort_values(['Id', 'SubId', 'Start'])
```

Extract maximum time intervals, since they will nullify any other intervals

```py
all_df = df[(df['Start']==pd.to_datetime('1990-01-01')) & (df.End==pd.to_datetime('2099-12-31'))]
```

Merge all adjacent time intervals, by first removing all maximum intervals

```py
inter_df = df.drop(df[(df['Start']==pd.to_datetime('1990-01-01')) & (df.End==pd.to_datetime('2099-12-31'))].index)
day_diff = (inter_df['Start'] - inter_df['End'].groupby(['Id', 'SubId']).shift()).dt.days
inter_df['_group'] = (day_diff.isna() | day_diff.gt(1)).cumsum()
merged_inter_df = inter_df.groupby(['Id', 'SubId', '_group'], dropna=False, as_index=True)\
    .agg({'Start': 'min', 'End': 'max'})\
    .droplevel('_group')
```

Concat data frame with maximum interval and merged adjacent time intervals

```py
full_df = pd.concat([all_df, merged_inter_df])
full_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
full_df
```

Which yields me the expected result

```
        Start   End
Id  SubId       
42  1   1990-01-01  2099-12-31
2       1990-01-01  2099-12-31
43  1   1998-01-01  2001-12-31
1       2010-03-15  2021-12-31
2       1998-01-01  2021-06-30
```